# Getting highest number after COUNT based on age group in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: techs and members. A member can have only one tech (his/her favorite tech item).

```
techs: techid,tname
members: memberid,age,techcode
```

Sample Data is now (for techs):

```
techid    tname
  1        Mobile
  2        XBox
```

Members:

```
memberid   age   techcode
  1         8     1
  2         18    1
  3         11    2
  4         42    1
```

It goes on.....

Now, the first report/query that was of interest was to get the total number of popularity of each tech item per age group. For that, the following query did a good job.

```
select tname, '0-10' = count(case when age<=10 then 1 end)
,'11-20' = count(case when age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 then 1 end)
,'21-30' = count(case when age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 then 1 end)
,'31-40' = count(case when age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 then 1 end)
,'41-50' = count(case when age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 then 1 end)
,'51-60' = count(case when age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 then 1 end)
,'61-70' = count(case when age BETWEEN 61 AND 70 then 1 end)
,'71-80' = count(case when age BETWEEN 71 AND 80 then 1 end)
,'81-90' = count(case when age BETWEEN 81 AND 90 then 1 end)
,'91-100' = count(case when age BETWEEN 91 AND 100 then 1 end)
,'100+' = count(case when age >100 then 1 end)
from members,techs WHERE techcode=techid GROUP BY tname
```

The next report that I want is now to get the most popular item per age group. The current output for example is:

```
tname    0-10  11-20

Mobile   7     1
XBox     4     20
```

The next output I want is basically Mobile is most popular for 0-10, XBox is popular for 11-20 years old. The output I want now is roughly:

```
Age    Highest     Tech

0-10   7         Mobile
11-20  20        Xbox
```

I don't really have a query now. I attempted doing MAX() on each age-range but it failed cos an aggregate cant run over an aggregate. I am a bit lost on how to get around it so no real query attempt to show.

Comment: The problem is the data format you created, if you first group by with the range, so that your data will have name + group + count, then you can take select biggest of every group with rank()

Comment: please add some sample table data and the expected result - as well in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: @JamesZ I have updated my question. Can you give me a hint on how to go about it? The query can be rewritten, obviously, to get the desired output.

Comment: @TheGameiswar how about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to do it using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**, but also using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) instead of the `case` expression.

```
;with AgeGroup as (
  select *
  from (values 
      (0 ,10 ,'0-10')
    , (11,20,'11-20')
    , (21,30,'21-30')
    , (31,40,'31-40')
    , (41,50,'41-50')
    , (51,60,'51-60')
    , (61,70,'61-70')
    , (71,80,'71-80')
    , (81,90,'81-90')
    , (91,100,'91-100')
    , (100,null,'100+')
      ) as t(ageMin,ageMax,AgeGroup)
)
, cte as (
select
    AgeGroup
  , Highest = count(*)
  , Tech = tname
  , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by ageGroup
      order by count(*) desc
      )
from AgeGroup ag
  inner join members m 
    on m.age >= ag.ageMin
   and m.age <= ag.ageMax
  inner join techs t
    on m.techcode = t.techid
group by AgeGroup, tname
)
select ageGroup, Highest, Tech
from cte
where rn = 1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KMASZX6347

If you wanted to show age groups for which you had no data, you could change the `inner join`s to `left join`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate by both dimensions at the same time (in rows, not columns).  Then use `row_number()` to get the most common value:

```
select ta.*
from (select tname, agegrp, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by agegrp order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from members m join
           techs t 
           on m.techcode = t.techid cross join
           (values (case when age <= 10 then  '0-10'
                         when age <= 20 then '11-20'
                         . . .
                    end)
           ) v(agegrp)
      group by tname, agegrp
     ) ta
  where seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- `cross apply` provides a convenient method for assigning an alias to an expression.
- The value your want to get is called the `mode`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and example Gordon. Lemme try it.

Comment: any idea where age column is not found when i run the query?

Answer (score 0):

Using `RANK() OVER` and `UNION` can get you the results you are after:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Age, Total, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Total DESC) AS RankByTotal, Tech
        FROM(


        SELECT '0-10' Age,
        sum(A.[0-10]) Total
        ,Tech
         FROM(
                SELECT tname, Tech
                ,'0-10'  = COUNT(case when age  between 0 and 10 then 1 end) 
                FROM members m
                LEFT JOIN techs t on techcode= techid
                Group by tname, Tech) A
         Group by Tech ) B

UNION ALL 

SELECT TOP 1 Age, Total,    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Total DESC) AS RankByTotal, Tech
        FROM(

            SELECT '11-20' Age,
            sum(A.[11-20]) Total
            ,Tech
             FROM(
                SELECT tname, Tech 
                ,'11-20' = COUNT(case when age between 11 and 20 then 1 end)
                FROM members m
                LEFT JOIN techs t on techcode= techid
                Group by tname, Tech) A
         Group by Tech) B
```

This approach means a `UNION` for each age group, which is probably not an ideal approach. 
However, it works!

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ i started writing it before you got any of the pro answers, just in case you were stuck with zero replies